# One user is not able to login

Tags: user-profile, login

I have an internal company site that all domain users have access to.  Recently I have one user that cannot access the site because the site is constantly requesting logging in but will not accept the credentials.  I have changed the password through Active Directory to make sure that the whole domain saw their credentials correctly.

No other user gets this and this user can access everything else on the network with their network credentials.  I don't want to make massive changes to the SharePoint server as no one else is having issues.  Any ideas of where too look for a fix?

Comment: Ask the user to add the site into the trusted sites in `Internet Options` (Internet Explorer)

Comment: It already is via GPO.

Comment: Is this a new user? Did you check when was the last time User Profile Synchronisation service ran?

Comment: No this isn't a new user.  And the User Profile Service is and has been running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was an issue with the user's profile on the local machine.  Deleting the profile was the ticket.